# Eclipse finds the same file twice, by absolute and relative path

Tags: c++, eclipse

Using C++ in Eclipse 4.4.2 on OS X 10.10.2

When running the "Open Declaration" command on a constructor of a specific class, Eclipse brings up a dialog and asks me to select one of two header files.  The odd part is that the two header files it lists are actually the same file, but one is being referenced by its relative path to the project, and the other is referenced by its absolute path.

The two files open in separate tabs, and different parts of the text are selected in each one, due to the "Open Declaration" command.  The version with the relative path selects what I would expect: the name of the constructor in its prototype in the header file.  The version with the absolute path selects the correct length of text, but offset 5 characters down the line.  This makes me suspect that the problem could be coming from a cached version of the file, though I can't find one.

This occurs for one specific class and file; others work fine.  I have disabled Linked Resources with no effect.  I have cleaned the build files both using the makefile and manual deletion, but the problem continues to exist.

The reason I initially noticed this problem is because Eclipse displays a warning that one of the members of that class "was not initialized in this constructor".  However, that member no longer exists; it was removed a few versions ago.

Comment: Right click your project and find `Index | Rebuild Index` (or something like that, I'm working from memory). This will rebuild the database it uses for this type of thing.